# How to determine if the checkbox has been checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a validation for the borrow button that when pressed but there is no item that has not been check it supposed to show a prompt but what is happening is it will not show a prompt and also it will not save into the database obviously. How would I try to do this.

Below is the code for javascript. (I don't know if this is even right)

```
$(".uniform_on").change(function(){
    var max = 1;
    if ($(".uniform_on:checked").length < max) {
        $(".uniform_on").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        alert('Please Check the item of equipment to be borrowed!');
        $(".uniform_on:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(".uniform_on").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Please help I am not mostly aware of the code since I only customize the code on my own and I have a limited knowledge on this kind of stuff. What if I press Borrow Button without checking the checkbox; how do I validate this that the user would check something first before pressing borrow again. Thanks.

This is the whole code for my Borrow

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include('navbar_borrow.php'); ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="margin-top">
            <div class="row">   
                                <div class="alert alert-info">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                    <strong><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Borrow Table</strong>
                                </div>

        <div class="span12">        

        <form method="post" action="borrow_save.php">
<div class="span3">

                                            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Borrower Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <select name="member_id" class="chzn-select"required/>
                <option></option>
                <?php $result =  mysql_query("select * from member")or die(mysql_error()); 
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['member_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="control-group"> 
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Due Date</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text"  class="w8em format-y-m-d highlight-days-67 range-low-today" name="due_date" id="sd" maxlength="10" style="border: 3px double #CCCCCC;" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group"> 
                    <div class="controls">

                                <button name="delete_student" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Borrow</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                        <div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Select Equipment</strong></div>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th>Acc No.</th>
                                        <th>Equipment Description</th>                                 
                                        <th>Category</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>status</th>
                                        <th>Add</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                  <?php  $user_query=mysql_query("select * from equipment where status != 'Archive' ")or die(mysql_error());
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
                                    $id=$row['equipment_id'];  
                                    $cat_id=$row['category_id'];

                                            $cat_query = mysql_query("select * from category where category_id = '$cat_id'")or die(mysql_error());
                                            $cat_row = mysql_fetch_array($cat_query);
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">


                                    <td><?php echo $row['equipment_id']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['equipment_description']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $cat_row ['classname']; ?> </td> 
                                    <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?> </td> 
                                    <?php /*  <td><?php echo $row['equipment_description']; ?></td> */ ?>
                                      <td width=""><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td> 
                                    <?php include('tooltip_edit_delete.php'); ?>
                                    <td width="20">
                                                <input id="" class="uniform_on" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >

                                    </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <?php  }  ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                </form>
            </div>      
            </div>      
<script>        
$(".uniform_on").change(function(){
    var max = 1;
    if( $(".uniform_on:checked").length < max ){

        $(".uniform_on:checked").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                 alert('Please Check the item of equipment to be borrowed!');
        $(".uniform_on:checked").removeAttr('disabled');

    }else{

         $(".uniform_on").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
</script>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

---

Made changes and it work for the validation part now for the transaction part where I would want to borrow it won't save to the database but it prompted only that you have borrowed
CODE new borrow button:

```
<input  name="delete_student" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Borrow" onClick="return validationfunction();" />
```

CODE for the javascript:

```
<script>
function validationfunction() {
    if($(".uniform_on:checked").length > 0 ) {
         alert('Equipment has been borrowed.');
         return true
    }
    else {
         alert('Please check the item of equipment to be borrowed!');
         return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is JavaScript and jQuery, not PHP ... also, i see 0 ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all its a javascript and jQuery code.

Call this function on click of a bowrrow button to check if the checkbox is checked or not like below.

```
function validationfunction() {
    if($('.uniform_on').is(':checked')) {
         // Your code goes here.
    }
    else {
         alert('Please Check the item of equipment to be borrowed!');
         return false;
    }
}
```

Call this function on click of your button as follow.

```
<input type="submit" value="Borrow Button" onClick="return validationfunction();" />
```

Comment: You could also just return `$('.uniform_on').is(':checked')` directly without using a if/else statement.
And indeed, the biggest problem here is that he don't call the validation function on the button click...

Comment: True, no need for first function. Edited! He is "trying to create a validation for the borrow button that when pressed" So he can just use above function for validation.

Comment: I do not get it?? Promise; what code will I insert there and how do i call it to the borrow button then??

Comment: Check edited answer. You can call the validation function on click as mentioned.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  but it won't let me borrow anything now.. it is like disabled button...now how would I do the if where one is already checked???

Comment: @Alok I already edited my post hope you see it my further question is there

Comment: @Chouny make the input type to "submit" and that will submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

As @SpYk3HH already mentioned that the part of you code you have posted here is not PHP. But as per reading your complete post. I can guess that you are basically having some issue while receiving post data at Back-end (PHP) side.

Actually, [HTML Element Checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) are usually play role as BOOL values (true/false). So if the Checkbox is selected you will get the Checkbox Value in Post Data otherwise you won't receive it.

**How to handle this situation:**

Well, this is something about to play with your code, you should make an array before inserting your data in the Database:

```
$myData = array();
$myData['key1'] = $_POST['key1'];
$myData['key2'] = $_POST['key2'];
/*
    As you can see we are handeling if the Checkbox was not seleted and giving it the value '0' in this case.
*/
$myData['checkbox_key'] = !empty($_POST['checkbox_key']) ? $_POST['checkbox_key'] : 0;


// then insert your $myData array in to database or do anything you wants to do.
```

**Furthermore, you can also validate your Checkbox before submitting the form:**

```
function validate_it(){
     if( $(".yourClassName:checked").length > 0 ){
         // Submit it or anything else
     }else{
         // alert or warn the user!
     }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind, if he's using jQuery to ajax validate the page, that unchecked checkboxes will not be serialized, thus `$_POST['key']` may not exist

Comment: How about I submit the form without checking anything how should I edit the code for this??

Comment: `$myData['checkbox_key'] = isset($_POST['checkbox_key']) ? $_POST['checkbox_key'] : 0;`

Comment: @SpYk3HH yeah, the PHP code example I have given is just for only 1 Checkbox. And yes Chouny you can do that, but in this case you have to make checks for your multiple Checkboxes as I have done for only ONE.

Comment: @Chouny I hope you will fix the issue by following this trick. And don't forget to mark as correct this answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: @Chouny please check my updates for Client side validation as well.